# Alguien sabe como se hace un update en springBoot de un campo en donde ya existe una llave primaria?

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, spring

Estoy atascado aqui con esta funcionalidad, estoy tratando de crear un servicio rest @PutMapping para hacer el update de un campo especifico de la tabla de `usuario`, pero por alguna razon que no entiendo me esta dando un error al enviar la peticion con postman, adjunto pantallazo del error a continuacion:

[image: Error en consola despues de mandar la peticion]

Estoy teniendo dos errores uno es que no se porque en lugar de enviarse como un update se esta enviando como si fuera un nuevo registro como si no estuviera tomando el update y lo otro es que dice que ya existe la llave (login), `llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «usuario_login_key»` aunque la primary key en la base de datos es el id `seq_id`

Me gustaria saber que estoy haciendo mal y como se deberia hacer correctamente un update con springBoot, en realidad el unico campo que necesito actualizar es el de `passwordc` que es una columna donde se alojara el password encriptado.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

Modelo:

```
package com.ssc.test.cb3.controller;


imports ...

/**
 * Class to handle REST services and APIs for the Customer's class
 *
 * @author ssc
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/users")
//@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @PutMapping("/updateUser/{id}")
    private ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") String username, @RequestBody User user){
        User existentUser = userService.getUser(username);
        System.out.println("Existent user: " + existentUser);
        existentUser.setPasswordc(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPasswordc()));

        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.createUser(user));   
    }

}
```

The service class:

package com.ssc.test.cb3.service;

```
imports...

/**
 * Class to prepare the services to be dispatched upon request regarding Customers. 
 * @author ssc
 */

@Service 
@Transactional 
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);  // details from user loaded by getting the username
        if(user == null){
            log.error("User not found in the database");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found in the database");
        } else {
            log.info("User found in the database: {}", username);
        }
        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        user.getRoles().forEach(role -> { 
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        });
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

    /**
     *  Method to get details from a user by the username
     * @param username key that helps to identify the user we want to retrieve from the database
     * @return the user details. 
     * @throws UsernameNotFoundException 
     */
    public User getUserDetailsByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);  // details from user loaded by getting the username
        if(user == null){
            log.error("User not found in the database by that username");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found in the database by that username");
        } else {
            log.info("User found in the database: {}", username);
        }
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param id
     * @return 
     */
    public User getUser(String username){
        log.info("Fetching user {}", username);
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }


    /**
     * Functionality to create a new user
     * @param user receives an objet User to be saved on the database
     * @return the action of saving the user in the database. 
     */
    public User createUser(User user){
        log.info("Saving new user {} to the database", user.getName());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setPasswordc(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPasswordc()));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    } 

}
```

Repositorio

```
package com.ssc.test.cb3.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.ssc.test.cb3.model.User;

/**
 * Class that extends to the repository for database management queries with table Usuario
 * @author ssc
 */

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Clase Modelo

```
package com.ssc.test.cb3.model;

imporst...

/**
 * Class that models the entity User as table of the database
 * @author cardo
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int serie;

    @Column(name = "login")  
    private String username;   // Username...

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String name;

    private String password;

    @Column(name = "perfil")
    private int profile;

    private String email;

    @Column(name = "activo")
    private boolean status;

    private String passwordc;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al enviar `user` dentro de tus parámetros de entrada, tu servicio asume que es un nuevo registro, ya que no obtuvo esos datos mediante una consulta SELECT. Para evitarlo, debes modificar la clave en la variable `existentUser` e invocar al método save con `existentUser` como parámetro. Debes reemplazar las líneas de tu clase **UserController**:

```
existentUser.setPasswordc(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPasswordc()));
return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.createUser(user));
```

Por las siguientes líneas

```
existentUser.setPasswordc(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPasswordc()));
return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.createUser(existentUser);
```